# Logging app like Google Forms/Sheets but private and offline

Tags: offline, phone, forms, google-drive

I have been using Google Forms as a logging app, creating a custom form, then saving a link to it on my phone's desktop, and then when I want to log my car's tire pressure or my cat's weight, for instance, I click the appropriate Form and fill in the values and they get added to a Google Sheet with a timestamp.

The ideal software would allow me to easily (without programming) create forms like Google Forms does, with options like radio buttons, checkboxes, explanatory text and images, numerical input fields (recognized by phone so it gives me a numerical keypad instead of a full keyboard), etc.

Basically the only differences from the actual Google Forms is that:

1. they should not be publicly accessible, so other people can't find them and type stuff into them
2. they should work without an internet connection, so more like a phone app that saves to the phone itself (and then syncs with a computer or cloud spreadsheet app when connection is established?) rather than a web page that saves to a server

Being able to fill out the form both on my computer and my phone is nice, but I guess not mandatory.  It could be a pure phone app.

Answer (score 1):

#### **[My Data](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.portofarina.mydata)**

It is a very simple database application that lets you keep records in table or in form format. Here are some features according to your requirements:

- Includes several field type: Text, integer, real, checkbox, image, date and time, phone number, etc...
- Number fields cause the numerical keypad to activate
- Ability to switch between table and form view
- No Programming involved
- Data is saved on the SD card (private)
- Works offline
- Backup and restore from cloud services

You cannot edit your database from a computer, but you could export/import tables from spreadsheet software using the csv format

[image]

Comment: The link doesn't work. Looks like it has now been renamed as PortoDB Database. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.portofarina.portodb

Answer (score 1):

You can use Clappia (https://clappia.com)

1. You can design forms with all the fields you mentioned
2. You need to download Clappia app to access all such forms inside one common app
3. The forms won't be publicly accessible unless you allow
4. It will be free for your use case
5. Works offline. Submitted data will be synced whenever you are back to the internet zone.

Disclaimer: I am associated with Clappia

Comment: You have posted three answers which all link to your site in the last 12 minutes. Please take a moment to review the [promotion guideline.](/help/promotion)