# Google Forms but offline for Windows

Tags: windows, survey, forms

I'm looking for a simple way to make forms or survey that save information in spreadsheets or in a database on the local computer.  Google forms are great, but they don't work offline. Anybody have ideas for something that could work on Windows?  (Not Android as mentioned in [this post](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/13386/logging-app-like-google-forms-sheets-but-private-and-offline).)

Comment: Shall it run on one PC only or does it need to be distributed (e.g. by email) and the results collected back (e.g. as XML file)? Any price?

Comment: It only needs to run on one PC, the results do not need to be distributed. Free or inexpensive is preferred, I don't think this needs to be a very sophisticated program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single computer you can use the [LibreOffice](http://www.libreoffice.org/) database [Base](http://www.libreoffice.org/discover/base/).

- Free, **gratis** & open source
- Cross Platform, Windows, OS-X & Linux
- LibreOffice Base provides wizards to help users who are new to database design (or just new to the software) to create tables, queries, **forms** and reports.
- Results can be output in a number of formats including pdf.
- Of course you also get a full office suite as a part of the bundle.

Comment: Thanks! That's really helpful, I don't know why I didn't think of that. I don't have enough reputation for my upvote to count for you right now, but it's in the system for when my reputation does reach